# Evaluating Radical Expressions (which step went wrong?)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So the  equation is $$\sqrt[3]{-3} * (\frac{1^{}} {375^{}}){^{1/3}{}} $$

Step 1: rewrite as $$-3^{1/3} *(\frac{1^{}} {375^{}}){^{1/3}{}} $$
Step 2: evaluate $$ (\frac{-3^{}} {375^{}}){^{2/3}{}}$$ 
Step 3: inverse $$(-\frac{375^{}} {3^{}}){^{-2/3}{}}$$
Step 4: divide $$ (-\frac{125^{}} {1^{}}){^{-2/3}{}}$$
Step 5: inverse to remove neg exponent $$(-\frac{1^{}} {125^{}}){^{2/3}{}}$$
Step 6: evaluate  $$-\frac{1^{}} {25^{}}{^{}{}}$$
What am I doing wrong here? Please avoid just writing down the numbers, explanations/rules would mean a lot thanks guys.

Comment: You made a mistake in step 2. Note that $a^x\cdot b^x = (ab)^x \neq (ab)^{x+x}$.

Comment: So we don't multiply exponents with a different base?

Comment: Let's consider real numbers $a, b, c.$  $$a^b\cdot c^b = (ac)^b, \;\text{ whereas }\;a^b\cdot a^c = a^{b + c}.$$  Only the first identity holds in this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiplication cannot be done with numbers of different bases.  example 
$$
2^3 \cdot 3^2 \neq 6^5
$$
As can be show easily thus you went wrong in step 2.

Comment: Actually, the better example, would be $2^3\cdot 3^3 = (2\cdot 3)^3 = 6^{3}$; your example uses different numbers with different exponents.  In this question, the exponents are the same.

Comment: @amWhy that was helpful! I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 3):

$$(-3^{1/3}) \times \left(\frac 1{375} \right)^{1/3} =- \left ( \frac 3{375}\right)^{\color{red}{1/3}} $$

Since, $$a^x \times b^x =(ab)^x$$

Comment: You lost a sign in the end.

Comment: And I asked to have some explanations and not just the numbers..

Comment: @amWhy Thanks for noticing. Edited.

Comment: This is the better answer.

Comment: yes this is a better answer :) +1

Comment: I liked the other answer due to the fact that he respected my request to explain in words.  Especially with amWhy's input, really helped me out :).

Comment: No problem @Lani. It's your freedom to choose best answer. :-)